# Cypress testing autocomplete input with ajax request

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to test an autocomplete input with cypress. When a user types something onto the input, an ajax request will be sent and display a list of the available options. The gist is that cypress needs to wait for the request to complete, if not there'll be no list to choose.

[image: Sample input]

The command below works most of the time but I'm looking for a better/efficient solution. The command accepts the element and the data for cypress to enter.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("autocomplete", (element, data) => { 
    cy.get(element).type(data).then(()=>{
        cy.wait(2000) // waiting for ajax to complete
        cy.get(".selectize-dropdown-content .option")
        .contains(data)
        .click()
    })
})
```

Comment: If it sends an AJAX request, could you use `cy.intercept(<AJAX path>).as('someAlias')` and then `cy.wait('someAlias')` for the AJAX call to finish? Or do something with the AJAX request's status code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wait, I would suggest using `cy.intercept()`, to intercept the request and then wait for it to get resolved.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("autocomplete", (element, data) => {
  cy.intercept('POST', '/somepartofurl').as('ajaxreq') //check the endpoint that is being triggered in chrome dev tools and mention here
  cy.get(element).type(data).then(() => {
    cy.wait('@ajaxreq') //Wait till the request is resolved
    cy.get(".selectize-dropdown-content .option")
      .contains(data)
      .click()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to waiting for `cy.intercept()` is to wait for the list to contain the search value.

Your code is nearly correct to do that, but you need to switch `cy.get(selector).contains(data)` for `cy.contains(selector, data)`. The latter command will retry until the text is found (so it waits for the request to populate the list)

You only have a 2 second wait, that's within the standard 4 second retry time Cypress applies (otherwise add a timeout option to increase it).

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("autocomplete", (element, data) => { 
  cy.get(element)
    .type(data)         // typing in the data may not be sufficient
    .trigger('change')  // may also need to trigger the change event
    .then(() => {
      cy.contains(".selectize-dropdown-content .option", data)// automatic retry here
                                                              // until list is populated
        .click();
  })
})
```

---

**What's the problem with `cy.intecept()` in this scenario?**

A lot of autocomplete components have some caching built in, so that if the user types then deletes the types again the ajax request is not sent again.

So there's a chance that `cy.intercept()` will not fire every time, depending on how complicated you make your test scenario.